# Route executes multiple times automatically

Tags: php, session, url, symfony-2.3

I'm sending email using `Swiftmailer` in **symfony2.3** and sets `flashBag` message that let user that email sent successfully. Fot this, i have created route and calling it from hyperlink of account page. But, my issue is when i access route using that hyperlink from page then route will execute only once that is fine and if i copy that route url and paste to url bar of browser and access it then my route action function will execute two times instead of single time. Here is my code.

**routing.yml**

```
user_resend_email:
    path:     /resend_email
    defaults: { _controller: UserBundle:User:resendEmail }
```

**UserController.php**

```
public function resendEmailAction(Request $request) {

    $userManager = $this->get('fos_user.user_manager');
    $user = $this->getUser();
    if($user) {
        $body = $this->container->get('templating')->renderResponse('UserBundle:Emails:email.html.twig');
        $resend_email = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
                ->setSubject("Welcome ".$user->getUsername()."!")
                ->setFrom('do-not-reply@mydomain.com'))
                ->setTo($user->getEmail())
                ->setBody($body->getContent())
                ->setContentType('text/html');

        $this->container->get('mailer')->send($resend_email);
        $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add('success', sprintf('Email has been sent successfully'));
    } else {
        $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add('danger', 'No user found!');
    }
    return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('user_account'));
}
```

I have googling this issue but could not find exact solution.

Comment: Have you check your logs? Does your access log shows multiple request?

Comment: yes, it shows multiple requests

Comment: Are they exactly the same? What if you try another browser?

Comment: i have tested in all the browsers but same issue in all. have solved it by changing my logic but want to know the reason behind and how to prevent this issue.

Comment: Did you look at the Web Debug Toolbar? Can you see multiple requests in app_dev.php/_profiler/search?limit=10 ?

Comment: No, i didn't check it. let me check it

Comment: Yes, It shows multiple requests there

Comment: All 200 status code?